# How to alter entity reference autocomplete field drupal 7

Tags: ajax

I have a node which have entity reference autocomplete widget field. I am referencing node of particular content type. But when I come to select node from entity reference field it shows all node created on particular content type. I don't want all node of  a content type only wants those node created by current user. Following code is working for select list and I am able to filter node created by specific user where $cType is the name of content type.

```
    function nirvana_item_offer($cType) {
      global $user;
      $nirvanaQuery = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->condition('uid', $user->uid, '=')
        ->condition('type', $cType, '=')
        ->condition('status', 1, '=')
        ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
        ->execute();  
      $result = array();
      if($nirvanaQuery){
        $result['_none'] = '- None -';
        foreach ($nirvanaQuery as $node) {
          $result[$node->nid] = $node->title;
        }
      }  

      return $result;
    }
```

Above function is returning only those node created by current user. How can I achieve same for autocomplete widget.

Comment: I got my answer here. (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118951/allow-user-to-use-entity-reference-to-nodes-they-own) This is exactly what I want.